# How to make New TableViewController appear when a TableViewControllerCell is tapped Swift

Tags: swift, tableview

I am trying to make a TableViewController (in Swift) with categories of products (ex. Shoes, T-shirts, Candy, etc.) and whenever a cell is tapped, I would like it to move to a different TableViewController that has Sub-Categories.

To make it short: I just want to make a new Tableviewcontroller whenever a cell is tapped from the first tableviewcontroller.

So far I already have the first TableViewController and made a segue to another TableViewController, But Each cell goes to the same TableviewController, I would like it for each cell to go to a different TableViewController Whenever it is tapped.

[image: This is how I would like it to be]

Is There any way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

For this , create segue to different viewcontroller you want to navigate from the current screen and then give each segue a unique identifier and use following method to navigate :

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
 if (segue.identifier == "categoryviewcontroller") {
        var VC2 : VC2 = segue.destinationViewController as VC2
 }
 if (segue.identifier == "productviewcontroller") {
    var VC2 : VC2 = segue.destinationViewController as VC2
 }
}
```

To navigate from UITableview Cell to different screen through segue use this way , here is link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/32640283/3400991

For detail visit [Segue](http://www.codingexplorer.com/segue-swift-view-controllers/) .

Comment: Hello, Thank You for your quick response...... so am i supposed to have multiple segues ? or just one from the cell to a different view controller ?

Comment: also will this make each cell go to a different view controller ?

Comment: For each cell to different you can , use UITableView didSelect delegate method also

Comment: Provided the exact link , how to navigate to different screen through tableview chck once in my updated answer

Comment: ok i will try it out and comment back whenever I am done.. thank you

Comment: hey whenever i clicked on the cells, they all took me to the same view controller. also i forgot to mention that i will be adding new cells to the first tableviewcontroller so whenever those cells are created i would like it to also be able to go to a different view controller

Comment: then simply create viewcontroller and pushed it like : self.navigationcontroller.pushviewcontroller(yourviewconroler, animated:true)